# Why does pyuv.pipe.start_read(...) cause Segmentation fault on pyuv.process.spawn?

Tags: python, process, spawn

Running this code with pyuv to spawn a process and capture its stdout and stderr:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pyuv


def on_read(pipe, data, error):
    print('data: ' + str(data))


def on_exit(process, exit_status, term_signal):
    print('Process Terminated - exit code: ' + str(exit_status))


def start():

    stdin_pipe = pyuv.Pipe(pyuv.Loop.default_loop())
    stdout_pipe = pyuv.Pipe(pyuv.Loop.default_loop())
    stderr_pipe = pyuv.Pipe(pyuv.Loop.default_loop())

    stdout_pipe.start_read(on_read)
    stderr_pipe.start_read(on_read)

    stdio = [pyuv.StdIO(stream=stdin_pipe, flags=pyuv.UV_CREATE_PIPE | pyuv.UV_READABLE_PIPE),
             pyuv.StdIO(stream=stdout_pipe, flags=pyuv.UV_CREATE_PIPE | pyuv.UV_WRITABLE_PIPE),
             pyuv.StdIO(stream=stderr_pipe, flags=pyuv.UV_CREATE_PIPE | pyuv.UV_WRITABLE_PIPE)]

    process = pyuv.Process(pyuv.Loop.default_loop())
    process.spawn(loop=pyuv.Loop.default_loop(), 
            args=['/usr/bin/wget', 'http://www.google.com'],
            exit_callback=on_exit,
            stdio=stdio)

    pyuv.Loop.default_loop().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

yields a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Commenting the 'start_read()' calls on the pipe instances works, but does not give me the stdout and stderr.

What am I missing?

Is this not the right way to capture stdout and stderr on spawned processes in pyuv?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my... placing the `Pipe.start_read()` callbacks *after* the  `Process.spawn()` did it.

```
process = pyuv.Process(pyuv.Loop.default_loop())
process.spawn(loop=pyuv.Loop.default_loop(), 
        args=['/usr/bin/wget', 'http://www.google.com'],
        exit_callback=on_exit,
        stdio=stdio)

stdout_pipe.start_read(on_read)
stderr_pipe.start_read(on_read)

pyuv.Loop.default_loop().run()
```

(*face-palm*)